# How can I check that my mediawiki in my virtual machine is not accessible from the internet?

Tags: webserver, virtual-machine, virtualbox, mediawiki

I downloaded from bitnami a virtual machine for mediawiki. The installation is done and I can access the website from host (my real operating system). During the installation i received the ip adress for the acess.

**How can I check that my mediawiki in my virtual machine is not accessible from the internet?**

It is for me important that the guest and webserver is only accessible by me and that there is no communication through host and the other way round.

(I am a beginner and searched the internet and decided to ask my question here. If it is the wrong place please write me a suitable place for this question.)

Comment: You can try [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: I tried it with my smartphone over wifi and it worked. But if I try to reach with my mobile internet it can not. I think than it will be possible to access it from others. I tried to change the VM adapter to host only and make settings (found in internet). At the moment my problem is that I have not got any communication. For example if I choose for the adapter 192.165.3.18  should it work for the website with 192.165.3.19?